# Proof verification [Function with finitely many discontinuities is integrable]

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Today at the end of class, our professor wrote this theorem on the blackboard. Could someone verify if my proof is correct?

> Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ be bounded with finitely many discontinuities $\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$. Prove that $f$ is integrable.

Let $I_1=[a,x_1-\delta]$, $I_2=[x_1-\delta,x_1+\delta]$, $\ldots$, $I_{k-1}=[x_n-\delta,x_n+\delta]$, $I_k=[x_n+\delta,b]$ and let $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{4Mk}$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. This gives rise to partitions $P_i$ for the intervals in which $f$ is continuous. In these intervals, we have $$U(f,P_i)-L(f,P_i)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2(k+1)}.$$ (In the remaining intervals, we introduce another partition.)

Let us consider the partition $P:=\bigcup_{i=1}^k P_i$. Since $P$ is a refinement of $P_i$, we have $U(f,P)\leqslant U(f,P_i)$ for all $i$; therefore $kU(f,P)\leqslant \sum_{i}U(f,P_i)$. Repeating the same procedure, we also have $I(f,P)\geqslant L(f,P_i)$ for all $i$; so $-kL(f,p)\leqslant \sum_{i}L(f,P_i)$. Therefore

$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)\leqslant \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k U(f,P_i)-L(f,P_i)$$

We wish to show that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\varepsilon$. For all intervals which don't contain a point of discontinuity, we already have $U(f,P_i)-L(f,P_i)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2(k+1)}$. In the remaining intervals, we perform a trick.

Since $f$ is bounded, we have $|f(x)|\leqslant M$ for some $M>0$.
Consider a partition $P_i$ of an interval which contains a point of discontinuity. We have
$$U(f,P_i)-L(f,P_i)=\sum_{p=1}^q (\sup f(x)-\inf f(x))\cdot (t_p-t_{p-1})\leqslant 2M\sum_{p=1}^q (t_p-t_{p-1})=2M\cdot 2\delta=4M\delta$$

Combining these (by an induction argument there are exactly $\frac{k-1}{2}$ intervals in which $f$ is discontinuous, and $\frac{k+1}{2}$ intervals in which $f$ is continuous), we get:

$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)< \frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\frac{\epsilon}{2(k+1)}+\frac{k-1}{2}\cdot 4M\delta \right)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+2M\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon.$$

$\square$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim that $U(f,P) \leq U(f,P_i)$ does not hold since $P$ is not a refinement of $P_i$. They are actually partitions on different sets: $P_i$ is a partition on one single interval and $P$ on the union of these intervals.